# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Can not connect to GhostDriver'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, port, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I'm trying to run `PhantomJS` from within `selenium.webdriver` on a Centos server. PhantomJS is in the path and is running properly from terminal. However in the script it appears to be launched, but afterwards cannot be reached on the specified port (I tried 2 different opened ports from my provider 29842 and 60099, they both are not working and neither launching it without a specified port).

The error happens here in `selenium.webdriver.common.utils`:

```
try:
    socket_ = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket_.settimeout(1)
    socket_.connect(("localhost", port))
    socket_.close()
    return True
except socket.error:
    return False
```

This is from my script (I tried without any parameters as well as writing the complete path to the executable and neither worked):

```
self.browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(
            port=29842,
            desired_capabilities={
                'javascriptEnabled': True,
                'platform': 'windows',
                'browserName': 'Mozilla',
                'version': '5.0',
                'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36"
            }
        )
```

And this the script that initialises the webdriver from `selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.service`. I checked and `subprocess.Popen` actually lauches phantomjs, the error happens in the while loop:

```
    try:
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.service_args,
                                        stdout=self._log, stderr=self._log)

    except Exception as e:
        raise WebDriverException("Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.", e)

    count = 0
    while not utils.is_connectable(self.port):
        print utils.is_connectable(self.port)
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if count == 30:
             raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to GhostDriver")
```

All the packages are the latest version: python 2.7, selenium 2 and phantomjs 1.9 binary with ghostdriver integrated. I made the same script work properly on my Ubuntu local machine, doing exactly the same things I did on the server. What is different on the server?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem and would find an answer.  I'm on Mac OSX.  Have you had any luck?

Comment: no I couldn't find anything to help me. please let me know if you find the solution. thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue on Ubuntu after upgrading to a new version.  I re-installed all of the nodejs and python packages, but what I think solved the issue was making sure the `nodejs` executable was symbolically linked to `node`.

These are the commands I used:

```
apt-get remove node nodejs
apt-get install build-essential python-dev phantomjs npm nodejs
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
npm install -g phantomjs
pip install selenium bson BeautifulSoup pymongo
```

Comment: don't forget to add sudo before apt-get

Answer (score 4):

Installing nodejs-legacy package on Linux Mint 14 solved this for me.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, this was a firewall issue. Phantom requires an open port to connect. If the port is blocked by a firewall, you'll get `WebDriverException("Can not connect to GhostDriver")`.

To fix:

1. Open a port.

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 65000 -j ACCEPT`

2. Create a PhantomJS driver that uses that port

`driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs', port=65000)`

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and found out what was causing it. In another tutorial on developing Facebook applications, I was told to nano in to /etc/hosts and change it from this-

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

to this-

```
127.0.0.1    test1.com
```

and save the file. Incidentally, PhantomJS() was not working anymore after that. I just went back in to the /etc/hosts file and switched it back to localhost

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

and it works again.

Answer (score 1):

I am testing a python/django application using selenium with phantomjs. Everything worked fine during first (and sometimes second test), but once running the next test, selenium printed the exact same error message.

Furthermore, if I ran phantomjs from console afterwards, I received the following node error:

```
child_process.js:1136 var err = this._handle.spawn(options); 
                                             ^

TypeError: Bad argument 
       at TypeError (native)
       at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1136:26)
       at exports.spawn (child_process.js:995:9)
       at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs:22:10)
       at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
       at Module.load (module.js:355:320)
       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
       at startup (node.js:129:16)
```

I tried reinstalling phantomjs via npm (both locally and globally) several times, but the behaviour persisted.

Eventually, I **uninstalled phantomjs via npm and downloaded the phantomjs bin from phantomjs.org** instead. Put that inside my /usr/local/bin (I am on MacOS) and got rid of the error since!