# How to install PhantomJS for use with Python Selenium on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, linux, selenium, raspberry-pi, phantomjs

I want to run a Python script using `Selenium WebDriver` with `PhantomJS` as a headless browser on my ***Raspberry Pi*** running Raspbian.

I originally wrote the script in OS X where it works  fine. But in trying to make it work on the Raspberry, I'm having problems.

When trying to run the script, I get this error:

```
raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/bin/phantomjs
```

Brief version of the script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

user_agent = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) " +
    "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36")

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = user_agent

serv_args = ["--ignore-ssl-errors=false", "--ssl-protocol=tlsv1", 
    "--disk-cache=false"]

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="/usr/bin/phantomjs", 
    desired_capabilities = dcap, service_arguments = serv_args, port=65000)
```

I have seen other people have problems resembling mine – with varying solutions – most seem to involve building PhantomJS yourself, or clone and install a Github branch adapted for Raspberry (which now is out-of-sync with the main PhantomJS project).

### Questions

- Does anyone know how to resolve the problem – and indeed what the problem really is about?
- If the solution involves installing the binaries manually to `/usr/local/bin` or such, how would I do that? The binaries available on the [PhantomJS webpage](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) is for `linux-x86` and `linux-i686`, so I'm assuming they won't work on an Raspberry Pi 2 B *ARM Cortex A-7 processor*.
- I have also tried to build PhantomJS myself according to these [instructions](http://phantomjs.org/build.html), but the process froze midway through. The Raspberry also doesn't meet the recommended hardware requirements for building.

### Background info

- I am using `Python 2.7.9`
- I have created a `virtualenv` and installed all the Python modules in it; e.g. `pip install selenium`, and attempt to run the script here
- I have installed the latest version of PhantomJS via `sudo apt-get install phantomjs`
- I have disabled my `ufw` firewall while testing

Comment: type `locate phantomjs` once you find it move it to `/usr/bin` ?  you might need to run `sudo updatedb` before running `locate` ... and you may have to apt-get install whatever package its part of ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Locate gives this output: http://pastebin.com/BBG2wgF0

Comment: hmmm well dang ... sorry no idea :/

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916123/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-can-not-connect-to-ghos/23309447#23309447 (basically reinstalling node and phantomjs)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks; I tried `apt-get nodejs` and `apt-get nodejs-legacy`, and then run the .py script, but same problem persists.

Comment: what does `which phantomjs` output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, `which phantomjs` gives `/usr/bin/phantomjs`, both without and with `virtualenv`.

Comment: Are you using raspbian?

Comment: Yes, Raspbian upgraded to the latest `apt-get update`. (Updated question with this info).

Comment: I just fired my pi up, I will see if I can get it working.

Comment: @Winterflags,  how exactly did you install phantomjs?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `apt-get install phantomjs`

Comment: The only option I had was `python-pyphantomjs`, maybe I need to enable another source, can you add the output of `apt-cache show phantomjs`?

Comment: Also what you get when you run  `phantomjs` from bash

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, `apt-cache show phantomjs`: http://pastebin.com/6NFsstKA

Comment: `phantomjs` from bash: http://pastebin.com/iQxa7R78

Comment: Are you running this through ssh to the pi or have a screen connected?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham SSH only!

Comment: The version is 1.4 which requires x11 or vfvb, I am actually getting an error in relation not being able to connect to X server, I am currently compiling from source, had a few issues so far but back compiling again so I will see if I can get it sorted, it will take a few hours on the pi so will let you know tomorrow.

Comment: ive been reading that lately people are using more headless chrome and firefox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172172/need-headless-browser-for-armv7-linux-processor

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok I will start with the solution, there is a version compiled for arm here [phantomjs-linux-armv6l](https://github.com/aeberhardo/phantomjs-linux-armv6l), on the pi run the following commands:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget https://github.com/aeberhardo/phantomjs-linux-armv6l/archive/master.zip
$ unzip master.zip
$ cd phantomjs-linux-armv6l-master
$ bunzip2 *.bz2 && tar xf *.tar
```

I added:

```
sudo cp phantomjs-1.9.0-linux-armv6l/bin/phantomjs  /usr/bin
```

So phantomjs will be on your path.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ phantomjs --version
1.9.0

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ phantomjs
phantomjs>
```

Now we have that done, time to test:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314771/how-to-install-phantomjs-for-use-with-python-selenium-on-the-raspberry-pi/36388824#36388824')
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="question-header"]/h1/a')
print(a.text)
print(driver)
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python test.py 
How to install PhantomJS for use with Python Selenium on the Raspberry Pi?
<selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver.WebDriver (session="b184e110-f9c4-11e5-aede-7f5c42f062d7")>
```

From the [faq](http://phantomjs.org/faq.html). *Starting with PhantomJS 1.5, it is pure headless and there is no need to run X11/Xvfb anymore.*.

I tried using *xvfb-run*  and exporting the display, using a shell script in init.d to start xvfb, I got a little further being able to run iceweasel from bash headless no problem but still no cigar when it came to phantomjs and selenium. I think it may just come down to an incompatibility between selenium and the version of phantomjs, regardless having 1.9.0  and  real headless browsing is a lot more desirable.

I was in the middle of setting up a toolchain and was going to try to compile myself when I found the link above, for anyone interested in cross compiling, [crosstools-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) makes life a lot easier.

I am running an arm6, there is also a [compiled version](https://github.com/hikomat/phantomjs-2.1.1-armv7) for arm7 using 2.0.0, the dependencies are:

```
sudo apt-get install flex bison gperf ruby perl libsqlite3-dev libfontconfig1-dev libicu-dev libfreetype6 libssl-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev python libX11-dev libxext-dev
```

The install procedure, I have extracted the binary to dropbox:

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/epj1rji9d239dco/phantomjs
chmod +x phantomjs
sudo cp phantomjs /usr/bin
```

The original github link is [phantomjs-2.0.0-armv7](https://github.com/hikomat/phantomjs-2.1.1-armv7)

Comment: Thanks so much for a great answer, research and solution! I will try this tonight! The effort was worth more than +50 Bounty so don't be surprised if I send some more your way once solution confirmed :)

Comment: No worries, I forgot yours was an arm7 but there are  lots of versions knocking around, I added a link to a version for the arm7 and the install procedure, it should work fine as it was compiled on a pi.

Comment: I will add a link to the binary itself in a minute

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!

Comment: `-bash: /usr/bin/phantomjs: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: @User $ cat /proc/cpuinfo    to see what armVersion and if you are installing right one

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it :

```
For 64-bit system, download phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 (12.6 MB).
For 32-bit system, download phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-i686.tar.bz2 (12.9 MB).

Step 1> $ wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

Step 2> $ tar -xvf phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

Step 3> $ cd phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64

Step 4> $ cd bin

Step 5> $ sudo cp phantomjs /usr/bin

To check phantomjs installed properly perform the following step : 

Step 6> $ phantomjs -h

To install the dependencies on Red Hat based systems:

Step 7> $ sudo yum install fontconfig freetype libfreetype.so.6 libfontconfig.so.1 libstdc++.so.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Download this phantomjs file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x063Krw6mZkRYW4K238a3EyRdklj5Evj

Replace to needed folder.

Give 777 chmod:
`chmod 777 phantomjs`

And try to use.

For Grafana - phantomjs file must be in a folder: `/usr/share/grafana/tools/phantomjs/`.

This binary file work to me on Banana pi M3 Debian 9. Architecture: arm armv7l. Kernel 4.20.7-sunxi