# Need headless browser for Armv7 linux processor

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, armv7, headless-browser

I need a headless browser for webscraping.Recently i tried 3 different headless browsers(**PhantomJS,Firefox,Chrome**).

When using **phantomJS**, it gives some **error (i.e):Armv7 processor needs GUI**.

then,am using **Firefox with geckodriver**, it shows **errors in the path and connection refused**.

so that i moved to **chrome headless browser with chromedriver**,but it also shows same **errors as Firefox**.

So,I need a correct headless browser for Armv7 processor.
Can anyone suggest solution for that or any other way to proceed further.

Comment: Update the question with the full exception of `connection refused`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing lower version of selenium fixed my issue in a similar case.

```
pip install selenium==2.53.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below procedure it worked for me.

geckodriver v0.19.0 the following versions are recommended:

Firefox 55.0 (and greater)
Selenium 3.5 (and greater)

Download the geckodriver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases. After downloading, extract it and make it executable(in linux `chmod +x path/to/geckdriver`).

```
from selenium import webdriver

geckoPath = 'path/to/geckodriver'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckoPath)
browser.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
body_html = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body")
print body_html.text
```

Comment: my armv7(dietpi) installing Firefox 52.0 only.so how to install firefox 55.0.I tried apt-get install Firefox and updated but it still 52.0

Comment: download it from https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/55.0/releasenotes/

Comment: i tried the above link but its not works.i followed the link for installation:[https://tecadmin.net/install-firefox-on-linux/#]